# Navigation drawer not opening with extended BaseActivity

Tags: android

I'm having an issue where my navigation drawer will not open, and for the life of me, I can't figure out what's causing it. Could someone take a look and possibly see something I'm missing?

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public ListView drawerList;
    public String[] layers;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    Intent twitch = new Intent(this, TwitchActivity.class);
    Intent community = new Intent(this, CommunityActivity.class);
    Intent esports = new Intent(this, ESportsActivity.class);
    Intent home = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle((Activity) this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_launcher, 0, 0)
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
            {
                actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                actionBar.setTitle(R.string.menu);
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


        layers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.layers);
        drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, android.R.id.text1,
                layers));


        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
                String selected = arg0.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                if(selected.equals("Twitch"))
                    startActivity(twitch);
                if(selected.equals("Community"))
                    startActivity(community);
                if(selected.equals("ESports"))
                    startActivity(esports);
                if(selected.equals("Home"))
                    startActivity(home);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

private Spinner spinner;
public static String region;
public static String name;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    //..........
```

My drawer_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Nav Drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Just to be sure since we don't have the complete onCreate() method of your MainActivity class... do you have another setContentView in there?

Comment: @fasteque Yes, I do have another setContentView there. I have edited my original post to be more clear.

Comment: Ok thanks. So, if in fragment_main.xml there's no android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout what you see is completely correct. You are setting a new layout (so you are not using the one set in the BaseActivity).

Comment: To be more clear: you don't have to set a new layout in your MainActivity if you're fine with the one set in the BaseActivity.

Comment: @fasteque Are you saying I can omit that line? Wouldn't doing so mean I have to add the fragment_main.xml content to the drawer_activity.xml layout? That would prevent me from extending BaseActivity in other activities as well, as then I wouldn't have their layouts, but fragment_main's? Sorry if this is way off base, I'm fairly new to working with things of this nature with Android

Comment: In the BaseActivity, you have a FrameLayout, which is the host widget for fragments. The content of each fragment, their layout, shall be provided in the Fragment onCreateView and not in the activity which hosts them. So, if the MainActivity will simply host fragments, you are completely fine using the BaseActivity layout (so omit the setContentView) and then set a layout for each fragment in each Fragment class you have.

Comment: @fasteque How would I handle this if I was not going to use fragments?

Comment: If each activity needs to have a different layout and you want to provide it with xml, simply include a DrawerLayout in each xml file for example. Maybe use the same id so you can create a base class that manage the drawer. Anyway it depends on the flow of your app, if you can I would suggest you the Fragment way.

Comment: @fasteque Thing is, I already have a good chunk of this project done, and I haven't worked too much with fragments yet to be comfortable with transferring it all over. I was simply attempting this method, as I have found on here that you can just set the navigation drawer up in a BaseActivity and simply extend it from activity to activity.

Comment: Yes, but as you have seen (also from the name of the layout of your MainActivity class), probably you have found an example based on fragments. Using fragments, it's really easy to have one navigation drawer because you can also simply have just one activity. In case you have two or more activities, the "brutal" way would be to have the navigation drawer in each layout and to optimize a bit things, you could give a common id and manage it in a base activity. You could also expose some methods from that class in order to override them in your activities.